# Set required foreign key via newly created inherited SQLAlchemy class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Say I have the following models:

```
class Root(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'root'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)


class Parent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    root_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('root.id'), nullable=False)
    type = db.Column(db.String(255))
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'parent', 'polymorphic_on': type}


class Child(Parent):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('parent.id'), primary_key=True)
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'child'}
```

I have a `Root` instance and want to create a `Child` instance to persist to my database. I'd prefer doing this without going via a `Parent` instance. How can I do this with SQLAlchemy? I'd hope to be able to do something like this:

```
r = Root()
db.session.add(r)

c = Child()
c.root_id = r.id  # Can I somehow do this without creating a Parent instance?
db.session.add(c)
db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can do EXACTLY this, if you don't forget to properly commit your `Root` first.

```
r = Root()
db.session.add(r)
db.session.commit()

c = Child()
c.root_id = r.id
db.session.add(c)
db.session.commit()
```